# Configure a regex pattern to apply after two forward slashes

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to configure a regex pattern to add a `#` at the end of a string after the second forward slash as follows:

- `/leisure/venuename/news` => `/leisure/venuename#/news`
- `/leisure/venuename/page/384` => `/leisure/venuename#/page/384`

The code below

```
gsub(/^(.*)(\/.*)$/, '\1#\2')
```

works as expected for the first pattern, but for the second pattern, it provides this:

- `/leisure/venuename/page#/384`

Is there a way to capture both groups with one pattern?

Comment: @Taemyr  (\/.*?\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+)(.*) http://regex101.com/r/tP2sW7/1

Comment: @vks /leisure/venuename_temp/page/384.  Amal's answer is the correct way forward for this problem, if you are explicit in what you are looking for greedy/lazy does not matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `.*` to match the forward slashes, be a little more explicit:

```
^(\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+)(\/.*)$
```

**Visualization:**

[image: From Debuggex.com]

**Explanation:**

```
^            # Assert position at the beginning of the line
(            # Begin first capturing group
    \/       #  Match literal '/'
    [^\/]+   #  Match any character that is not a '/', one or more times
    \/       #  Match literal '/'
    [^\/]+   #  Match any character that is not a '/', one or more times
)            # End of first capturing group
(            # Begin second capturing group
    \/       #  Match literal '/'
    .*       #  Match everything else
)            # End of second capturing group
$            # Assert position at the end of the line
```

[**RegEx Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/uL1cJ0/1)

Comment: thanks Amal, that worked a peach. Just a quick question, greedy means, in the simplest terms?

Comment: @user3868832: I'll just quote: "*The standard quantifiers in regular expressions are greedy, meaning they match as much as they can, only giving back as necessary to match the remainder of the regex.*". See this question for more details: [What do lazy and greedy mean in the context of regular expressions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/)

Comment: @user3868832 Greedy means that a quantifier, ie * or +, tries to match as much as possible before backtracking.  The other option is lazy, specified by `*?` or `+?` in which case it matches as little as possible.

Comment: @user3868832 For example in your regexp the quantifier is greedy.  So it first tries to match the whole input "/leisure/venuename/page/384" to the first `.*`.  This fails because it needs the next character to be a "\".  It then backtracs, trying "/leisure/venuename/page/383", which also fails.  Eventually it attemts to match the first quatifier with "/leisure/venuename/page" and then the rest of the regexp suceeds, so it considers this a match.

Comment: @Taemyr thanks dude. I think this gives me something to go on. Regex is scary.. I just need to try and understand it programatically like you have explained up there. There should be more straightforward explanations like you and Amal have provided.

Comment: @user3868832: You may want to check out this [interactive regex tutorial](http://regexone.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You are doing two things wrong.

1. You should not use `gsub` here.
2. You should not use `\2` here.

Do it like this:

```
"/leisure/venuename/news"
.sub(%r"((?:/[^/]*){2})", '\1#')
#=> "/leisure/venuename#/news"

"/leisure/venuename/page/384"
.sub(%r"((?:/[^/]*){2})", '\1#')
#=> "/leisure/venuename#/page/384"
```

Answer (score 0):

While it's possible to do this with a regular expression, I'm not sure that it's the more readable/maintainable route. I'd do it like this:

```
foo = '/leisure/venuename/news'.split('/')
foo[2] << '#'
foo.join('/') # => "/leisure/venuename#/news"

foo = '/leisure/venuename/page/384'.split('/')
foo[2] << '#'
foo.join('/') # => "/leisure/venuename#/page/384"
```

It's simple, clean and very readable, which is important when the code is going to be around a while.